# Similar to Nettles: What is it?

Tags: identification

The stalk is hairy.  It looks like Nettles but isn't though they often grown together.[image: Looks.like.nettles.but.aint[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuiAK.jpg)